String property as [Required] vs non-nullable when defining a class for EF Core
I'm new to Blazor and EF Core and I'm learning about the mapping between C# classes and the database tables created by EF Core.
While defining a class in C#, Intellisense will complain if I define a string property as not nullable as "it must contain a non-nullable value when existing constructor". So there are 2 options here and I would like you to explain to me the implications/differences of each alternative.

Mark the property as non-nullable and initialize it to an empty string.
Mark the property as [Required]

Another thing that I noticed is that marking the property as [Required] doesn't remove the warning, even though the property will need to have a value when creating the object?

and what exactly is your question?

It says clearly in the question. What are the differences/implications of each approach and why is the warning not getting removed when marking a property as Required.

It should be public required string Name { get; set; }

Related topic Working with Nullable Reference Types from EF Core official docs covers it all, I don't think it could be explained better here.

nullability has nothing to do with a property being required or not. It's often used to indicate that a property is optional, however null might be a valid value for your property depending on your business-domain. So these two things don't rerally fit one another.


Name cannot be null or ""(empty).

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }


Name cannot be null, but can be "" (empty)

public string Name { get; set; } =string.Empty;


Name can be null or ""(empty)

public string? Name { get; set; }


The [Required] attribute is about runtime validation, not about compile-time nullability. C#'s nullable reference types feature checks for potential null assignments at compile time, which is why the warning appears if the property is declared as string?. The attribute doesn’t change the fact that the property is nullable (string?), so the compiler warns you that the property might be null if you don’t set it to a value before use.
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string? MyProperty { get; set; }
}

var entity = new MyEntity();
entity.MyProperty = null; // This is allowed in C#.

If you try to save or validate an instance of this class, and MyProperty is null, the validation will fail, triggering a validation error. The [Required] attribute enforces that MyProperty must have a non-null (and non-empty) value during validation, but it itself does not enforce validation. Instead, it serves as a marker that you can use with validation logic. You must implement or configure validation logic to recognize and apply these constraints.

[Required] only comes into play if you implement validation that recognises it.  There's no built in implicit validation.

Agreed, the [Required] attribute itself does not enforce validation. Instead, it serves as a marker that you can use with validation logic. Just adding the [Required] attribute to a property does not automatically enforce validation. You must implement or configure validation logic to recognize and apply these constraints.

Why don't you add this information to your answer.

Some of the documentation around the [Required] attribute, particularly with strings, stems from Code First with EF6 and early .Net Core/ EF Core before Nullable reference types were introduced. If you had a string property in an entity, EF would default it to a Null-able varchar unless you explicitly marked it as [Required] or through configuration.
With EF Core since the introduction of null-able reference types if you define the property as string it would use, and expect a non-null-able backing column. This can be a nuisance for the CS8618 warning since our strings likely won't have desired defaults, we just want it to expect a value before saving. My public constructor would provide a value for all non-null strings/references, but EF cannot reliably use that constructor and benefits from a default constructor.
To avoid the warning you either have to initialize every reference, or you can use a null-able type with the [Required] attribute, or use the null forgiveness, I.e:
public string SomeValue { get; set; } = null!

I'm not a fan of spattering null forgiveness exclamations everywhere. Initialization with a default is usually fine for things like string but doesn't help with navigation properties:
[Required]
public Address? Address { get; set; } // Where AddressId is !null. 

I don't like the [Required] because when I check Intellisense it just reports as a null-able type, it doesn't indicate the fact it is tagged as required. Plus if it is Address? Address { get; set; } then everywhere I use newThing.Address. ... I'm going to get nagged about null-ability when Address actually cannot be #null, expecting newThing.Address!. ... I was just keeping the compiler/EF happy.
That leaves:
public Address Address { get; set; } = null! // yuck, I don't like finding these anywhere.

.. but definitely do not use:
public Address Address { get; set; } = new(); // This is nothing but bad news.

The work-around I use for Entities is that I will use the proper null-ability then if I get fed a CS8618 then I add the override to the default constructor:
public Address Address { get; set; } 

...

public SomeEntity( /* all non-nullable values */, Address address)
{
    // ...
    Address = address ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(address));
}

#pragma warning disable CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
protected SomeEntity() {}
#pragma warning restore CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.

... as my entities normally have a protected default constructor for EF to use along with a public constructor /w all required properties that my factory code uses to ensure entities are always created in a completely valid state. Inserting those #pragma is an intellisense code formatting option offered on the constructor. It's the lesser of two evils as I really dislike finding null forgiveness "bangs" and question marks, and "null!" everywhere.
